# Set cookies to a different https vendor site through CName

Tags: cookies, https, certificate, cname

I'm having difficulty setting cookies to a https vendor site through CName alias.
We have taken a similar approach with another vendor to get our OAuth authorization flow working but both our websites were served on http and all I had do to was set cookies on the .xyz.website.com domain for the vendor to be able to read our cookies and continue the rest of OAuth 2 flow (we have the complete backend supporting OAuth implemented)

For the cookies to be available for the vendor to read- we did a CName alias for auth.xyz.website.com to the vendors domain abc.vendorspace.net and since the cookies were set on ".domain.com" all the subdomains should be able to read the cookies.

Now I understand the exact same implementation might not work when both our websites are on ssl with their own separate certificates, I'm really trying close the gap here as I'm unable to tie that knot on how the cookies and the secure channel(ssl) can be set at the same time , what needs to be done to have certificates trust each other?